# Can't publish project plan to TFS

Tags: tfs, mapping, ms-project

I want to use a .MPP MS Project 2007 plan which has not yet been mapped to work items in TFS, the TFS project is empty, I mean that there are no work items at all. I want to synchronize with `http://localhost:8080/tfs/` so that I can transfer my entire business plan to TFS work items, but this is not working. I have tried doing this:

Open VS 2010 shell:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://localhost:8080/tfs/ /p:"MyProject" /f:"Z:\task.xml"
```

but I still can't publish to TFS in MS Project, I get this error:

`TF80006: Team Foundation needs a work item type to publish work items. Select a work item type for the work items you have added and then try again.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue:

1. Download and install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools plugin for VS2010 here.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)
2. Under `Tools > Process Editor > Work Item Types > Open WIT from Server` to obtain the work item type from a TFS project on your TFS server. I selected "Task".
3. Publish again, this time edit the lines that have validation errors. The fields in yellow will have to be changed accordingly. Or, you can disable validation by following [these steps.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/tfsgeneral/thread/8f492e74-77a6-4aca-994e-c525759f85dc)

Answer (score 1):

One of gotchas that bit me was that I did not set the Work Item Type in Project.  Once I set it to 'Task' I was able to publish my schedule to TFS.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the issue for me and I think should be marked as the answer